# How does the market respond when some suppliers of one product are forced to switch to supplying a similar product?

Tags: microeconomics, elasticity, elasticity-of-substitution

I'm interested in coming up with a basic model to describe the following simple situation.

Initially there is an equilibrium in the market for the consumption of product A and product B. Product A and B are similar, but not quite the same, and so there is a substituition effect.

Then there is an external force which means that some production of A is switched to B. I think this causes the following to happen:

- Supply of B increases while the demand is unchanged leading to a decrease in price, which then causes an increase in demand.
- Supply of A decreases while demand stays the same leading to an increase in price, which then causes a decrease in demand.
- Due to the low price of B, the high price of A, and the fact that the two products are somewhat substituitable, some people who usually consumed A would start consuming B instead.

I'd like to express this in mathematical form using the elasticities of demand for A and B, and I will also need some kind of "substituitability index" between A and B.

- $S_{A0}$ = Supply of A before the external force
- $S_{A1}$ = Supply of A directly after the external force
- $S_{A2}$ = Supply of A after an equilbrium has been reached again

If we say that initially the supply of A is $S_A0 = x S_B0$

And due to the external force, a proportion (z) of the production of A is switched to B, (i.e. $S_A1 = S_A0(1-z)=xS_B0(1-z)$)

$S_B1 = S_B0+zS_A0= S_B0(1+zxS_B0)$

I am trying to find S_A2 and S_B2 expressed in terms of the elasticities of A and B, as well as some kind of "substituitability index" between A and B.

I would seriously appreciate help on this, as I'm quite stuck.